# iOS Swift 3: does retain cycle happens in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckoutCell") as! CheckoutCell

    let product = shoppingCart[indexPath.row]

    var tfQuantity : UITextField!
    cell.clickEditAction = { [weak self] celll in
        guard let ss = self else { return }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Enter new quantity", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textfield) in
            tfQuantity = textfield
        }

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
            if tfQuantity.text == ""{
                return
            }

            if let newQuantity = Int(tfQuantity.text){
                product.quantity = newQuantity
                self.tbvCheckout.reloadData()
            }
            return
        }

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return cell
}
```

This line of code:

```
self.tbvCheckout.reloadData()
```

If I don't use [weak self] or [unowned self], does it create retain cycle between current object & UIAlertAction instance?
What if I use this code instead: tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: I would guess, that it will retain. A good way to test this is to add logger to the life-Cycle Methods of the VIewControllers. When Destroyed (when you dismiss the controller from the stack) will be called, you know, that it could free the object. When not, you can say that there is some object retaining. Also, I dont know if it is a good practice, but when ever I use `self` in a completion/hander/dispatch-Block I make a weak self variable

Comment: yes sure , because your cell for row at index call infinite time in your both cases.

Comment: What if I use this code instead: tableView.reloadData()?
in this case, I do not capture "self", the tableView variable is get from delegate method of UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

First, You have created a weak reference, but I don't see you using it in the code.

```
guard let ss = self else { return }
```

Any reference to self should be via this weak self variable **"ss"** that you have created.

Second, The alert action block should also have weak reference to self

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self] (action) in
        if tfQuantity.text == ""{
            return
        }

        if let newQuantity = Int(tfQuantity.text){
            product.quantity = newQuantity
            self?.tbvCheckout.reloadData()
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: ok I understand that part. but how about using this line of code: tableView.reloadData()?. I do not capture "self" here, the tableView variable is get from delegate method of UITableView